# Firebase Realtime Database - Database trigger structure best practice

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, triggers

I have some data in a Firebase Realtime Database where I wish to split one single `onUpdate()` trigger into two triggers. My data is structured as below.

```
notes: {
  note-1234: {
    access:{
      author: "-L1234567890",
      members: {
        "-L1234567890": 0,
        "-LAAA456BBBB": 1
      }
    },
    data: {
      title: "Hello",
      order: 1
    }
  }
}
```

Currently I have one `onUpdate()` database trigger for node `'notes/{noteId}'`.

```
exports.onNotesUpdate = functions
.region('europe-west1')
.database
.ref('notes/{noteId}')
.onUpdate((change, context) => {
  //Perform actions
  return noteFunc.notesUpdate({change, context, type:ACTIVE})
})
```

However, since my code is getting quite extensive handling both data and access updates - I am considering splitting the code into two parts. One part handling updates in the `access` child node and one handling the `data` child node. This way my code would be easier to read and understand by being logically split into separate code blocks.

```
exports.onNotesUpdateAccess = functions
.region('europe-west1')
.database
.ref('notes/{noteId}/access')
.onUpdate((change, context) => {
  //Perform actions
  return noteFunc.notesAccessUpdate({change, context, type:ACTIVE})
})

exports.onNotesUpdateData = functions
.region('europe-west1')
.database
.ref('notes/{noteId}/data')
.onUpdate((change, context) => {
  //Perform actions
  return noteFunc.notesDataUpdate({change, context, type:ACTIVE})
})
```

I am a bit unsure though, since both `access` and `data` are child nodes to the `note-1234` (noteId) node.

My question is - Would this be a recommended approach or could separate triggers on child nodes create problems?

Worth mentioning is that the entire `note-1234` node (both `access` and `data`) will *sometimes* be updated with one `.update()` action from my application. At other times *only* `access` or `data` will be updated.

Kind regards /K

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you've nested two types of data under a single branch, which is something the Firebase documentation explicitly recommends against in the sections on [avoid nesting data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data#avoid_nesting_data) and [flatten data structure](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data#avoid_nesting_data).

So instead of merely splitting the code into two, I'd also recommend splitting the data structure into two top-level nodes: one for each type of data. For example:

```
"notes-data": {
  note-1234: {
    author: "-L1234567890",
    members: {
      "-L1234567890": 0,
      "-LAAA456BBBB": 1
    }
  }
},
"notes-access": {
  note-1234: {
    title: "Hello",
    order: 1
  }
}
```

By using the same key in both top-level nodes, you can easily look up the other type of data for a note. And because Firebase [pipelines these requests over a single connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35931526/speed-up-fetching-posts-for-my-social-network-app-by-using-query-instead-of-obse/35932786#35932786) such "client side joining of data" is not nearly as slow as you may initially think.

Comment: Thank you Frank! :D I will begin by implementing two triggers and plan for a flattening of the data structure real soon. It will be a bigger job though since I already have code depending on the nested structure. :/ Will keep "flaten data structure" as a mantra in my mind from now on! ;) /K